# How can I set a custom 404 page on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I am trying to set a custom 404 page on Github Pages.

I have created a page here: http://garemoko.github.com/TinCanCoUK/404.html which works when visited directly.

However, if I go to http://garemoko.github.com/TinCanCoUK/foo.html I get the default Github 404 page.

Any ideas? I have the 404.html in both master and gh-pages directories.

**Background:**
This is particularly important for this site as I am moving from a mediawiki site that uses : in the urls which I can't replicate so I'm having to change all my URLs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this only works if you use a custom domain

https://help.github.com/articles/custom-404-pages

> Good to know: custom 404s only work when they are served from the root
>   of a Pages domain, for example a project using a custom domain or a
>   user pages repo. A custom 404 page on project pages that are not using
>   a custom domain will not work.

See [this](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) for setting up custom domains

Comment: Thank you. I have created the CNAME page but I can't work out the setting up DNS part. Am I supposed to type this into the git command line?

Comment: the dns settings would be entered in your dns providers website

Comment: eg. something like godaddy, namecheap etc, you do have a dns provider dont you?

Comment: Ok, I think I worked it out. I have changed the dns settings with the company I registered the domain with.

Comment: I changed the two A entries for ww and @, but left the MX ones unchanged. Is that right?

Comment: that sounds correct, now you'll just have to wait for it to tick over, you can try lowering the ttl as low as the provider will let you but it may be to late for that to have any effect for this change

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again this evening. It didn't have any value for TTL on the A rows, only on the MX ones.